# pressing back button show hidden div again on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage on which I hide an item (add class `hidden`) of a list on item's button click ... now I navigate to another page on website and then press back button of browser. I see the previously hidden item again in list. How can I hide the element permanently using `jquery`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you redirect, all javascript, and any changes made by it, is lost, period.

Comment: Is there a way to keep them permanent? I can do that using `localStorage` but I am looking for better solution.

Comment: There is no better solution, just other solutions, like storing the state in cookies or serverside.

Comment: You can also store some info in the URL itself. On change of DIV's state update the URL - when you go back JS can detect it and re-hide the DIV. That's the way most modern single-page apps work (see Google Maps, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to ask yourself "what STATE determines the fact that it is hidden?". This would affect how to answer your question very deeply, if your page has a user-configured state, the state should be saved and restored on page init. You can save your state in the "#hash" part of the URL or in localStorage.

In general, you can still do something like this:

```
function user_action_that_hides_the_div() {
  $div.hide();
  localStorage.setItem("that-div-was-hidden", true);
}

// on page init:
if (localStorage.getItem("that-div-was-hidden"))
  $div.hide();
```

Another solution could be to ALWAYS hide the div and SHOW it only if needed (and you need to determine at JS level whether you want to show that information.